# Delete part of src after a certain character - IFTTT

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, src, ifttt

I am using IFTTT with Wordpress, so every time that I create a post on reddit, the recipe creates a post on Wordpress.

```
<div><img src='http://www.thelolempire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/v1yfapih.jpg' style='max-width:600px;' /><br/><div>Tackling dummy</div></div>
```

The issue is that IFTTT is automatically adding in the `style='max-width:600px;'` element which then throws off my responsive template.

So having done some research i have tried to piece together the following code that could filter the element out:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' ,  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\filter_post_data' , '99', 2 );

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    $data['post_content'] = preg_replace('/(\ style.*)( style=\')/','', $data['post_content']);
    return $data;
}
```

However when I add it to functions.php...everything goes down. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried linting the file this function is in (`php -l`) ? Or any other debugging methods?

Comment: Any error? error.log or display_errors = on?

Comment: Hello, no i havent linted the function, and i cant see any errors. I must however point out i am not a coder - but have tried to make some reasonable deductions from someone elses issue. I think i may have typed something wrong.. :/ any ideas?